# Mirrored Cells: Intentional Circular Referencing

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to build a sheet that has "Mirrored Cells" i.e. I want several cells to display the same value and for that value to change in *all* cells if it changes in *any* cell.

For example:

```
Cell A1: "Apple"
Cell A2: "Apple"
Cell A3: "Apple"
```

If I change A3 to "Banana" I want my sheet to display "Banana" in Cells A1, A2 and A3. I know that if I set A1 = A3 and A2 = A3 I can accomplish this. However, I want to also have the ability to, say, change A1 to "Carrot" and have all three cells display "Carrot". I don't know how to force excel to take the circular reference for the set of three cells, where the value can be changed by addressing any cell.

P.S. - What I described is how I would like the behavior to "appear" to someone who's simply trying to update the sheet. If anyone has ideas for writing a VBA script that can automatically process this update (i.e. can be called automatically and behind the scenes each time a cell value is changed), I am happy to write one up and use it, programming the cells that belong in each circularly referenced set directly into the script.

Edit: I implemented the script provided by @silentsurfer and it worked well on a simple worsheet with values in A1:A3. I then implemented the named range feature that @pnuts suggested.

In my worksheet, I selected three cells (C3, C5, C7) and set them as the named range ("config3P"). I simply want @silentsurfer's script to monitor these three cells instead of A1:A3, so this is the changed code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c3P As Range
Dim xlCell As Range

Set c3P = Range("config3P")
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Intersect(Target, c3P) Is Nothing Then
    For Each xlCell In c3P
        xlCell.Value = Target.Value
    Next xlCell
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I would use this to ensure that groups of related items (in this case, electrical transformers) maintain consistent labeling across several parameters.

Comment: You can use a `Worksheet_Change` event for this.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams & @pnuts, `Worksheet_Change` was what I needed to make it all happen "behind the scenes" and the named range is what I think I'll need to define the set of cells in the worksheet and not to VBA script, which will allow the order of the cells to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pasting this to your worksheet code page in the VBA editor:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim chngRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range

    Set chngRange = Range("A1:A3")
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, chngRange) Is Nothing Then
        For Each xlCell In chngRange
            xlCell.Value = Target.Value
        Next xlCell
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @silentsurfer! That works perfectly - I'm going to try right now to tweak it a little bit for my needs.

I've lurked on stackoverflow for a while but this was my first time asking a question -- I'm thrilled at how helpful everyone has been. Now that I've got an account, I'll try to answer some questions and pay it forward!

Comment: Nice answer. FYI, you can slim your `For/Next` down to one line, I believe: `chngRange.Value = Target.Value`.

Comment: @DougGlancy you are mostly right. However, in some border cases you might get unexpected results, e.g. when pressing Delete while selecting multiple cells within the Target range